# Python: copying files group to subdirectories

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, directory-structure, distutils

I'm working with Python and I'd like to copy 3 files of a certain folder
`/Users/jake/Desktop/exp` to all the subfolders of other sub-directories belonging to the directory `/toyspace`:

```
/Users/jake/Desktop/toyspace/1A/AAA
/Users/jake/Desktop/toyspace/1A/BBB
/Users/jake/Desktop/toyspace/1A/CCC

/Users/jake/Desktop/toyspace/2B/AAA
/Users/jake/Desktop/toyspace/2B/BBB
/Users/jake/Desktop/toyspace/2B/CCC
```

So the subfolders names are the same for all the sub-directories. I wrote something like that:

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

def myfunc (source, destination):

    fromDirectory = source
    toDirectory = destination

    copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory)

    for subfold in toDirectory:
        myfunc(fromDirectory, subfold)
```

Where **source =**`/Users/jake/Desktop/exp` and **destination =**`/Users/jake/Desktop/toyspace`, but it returns me an error:

```
DistutilsFileError: could not create '/motif_list.txt': Read-only file system
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not used distutils but you can try to automate using the os command as below

```
import os
def copy_folders(source_dir, destination_dir):
    files = os.listdir(source_dir)
    for sub_folder1 in os.listdir(destination_dir):
        for sub_folder in os.listdir(destination_dir + sub_folder1 + '/'):
            for file in files:
                os.system('cp ' + source_dir + file + ' ' + destination_dir + sub_folder1 + '/' + sub_folder + '/')
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: It works, but by using this I copy the files from source_dir to destination_dir which is 1A or 2B in my example. I'd like to copy my files in source_dir to AAA, BBB, CCC that are sub-folders of the 1A and 2B sub-directories of the directory toyspace

Comment: @Barbanera Hey I have edited my answer to copy files from source dir to all the subdirectories. 

Note that this will only work for a depth of 2, you might have to work on a better iterator for a deeper structure.